# Working with external library in C++ (SVL library)

Tags: c++

I tried to install the [external library SVL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/public/dist/), that is given in the link. I did `make install` and it seems now I can import it as given in [documentation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/doc/svl.html)  using `#include <svl/some_header_files.h>`

Now I want to run some of my program to test. But I am struggling with it. I did

`g++ vertex.hh vertex.cc`

the program I want to work and it gives out,

```
In file included from vertex.hh:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/svl/Vec3.h:14:
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:25:10: error: unknown type name 'Real'
    Vec2(Real x, Real y);       // (x, y)
         ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:25:18: error: unknown type name 'Real'
    Vec2(Real x, Real y);       // (x, y)
                 ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:27:10: error: unknown type name 'ZeroOrOne'
    Vec2(ZeroOrOne k);          // v[i] = vl_zero
         ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:28:10: error: unknown type name 'Axis'
    Vec2(Axis k);               // v[k] = 1
         ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:32:5: error: unknown type name 'Real'
    Real        &operator [] (Int i);
    ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:32:31: error: unknown type name 'Int'; did you mean 'int'?
    Real        &operator [] (Int i);
```

and more similar errors, which is then followed by

```
In file included from vertex.cc:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/svl/Vec3.h:14:
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:25:10: error: unknown type name 'Real'
    Vec2(Real x, Real y);       // (x, y)
         ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:25:18: error: unknown type name 'Real'
    Vec2(Real x, Real y);       // (x, y)
                 ^
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:27:10: error: unknown type name 'ZeroOrOne'
    Vec2(ZeroOrOne k);          // v[i] = vl_zero
         ^
```

and more similar errors,
and in the end,

```
/usr/local/include/svl/Vec2.h:69:27: error: unknown type name 'Int'; did you mean 'int'?
    Vec2        &MakeUnit(Int i, Real k = vl_one);  // I[i]
                          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Can you tell me what is going on here? How can i fix this?

Here is the link to the two files `vertex.cc`and `vertex.hh`
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4cax5ftk2lssots/AAA62m2VnSZXqBfB65VfVqFTa?dl=0

New error using `#include "svl/SVL.h"`

```
In file included from vertex.hh:13:
./edge.hh:289:10: warning: unelaborated friend declaration is a C++11 extension; specify 'class' to befriend 'QuadEdge'
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
  friend QuadEdge;
         ^
         class
1 warning generated.
In file included from vertex.cc:12:
In file included from ./cell.hh:9:
./edge.hh:289:10: warning: unelaborated friend declaration is a C++11 extension; specify 'class' to befriend 'QuadEdge'
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
  friend QuadEdge;
         ^
         class
In file included from vertex.cc:12:
./cell.hh:293:10: warning: unelaborated friend declaration is a C++11 extension; specify 'class' to befriend 'CellVertexIterator'
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

Comment: Did you try to tell g++ to use svl include dir: `g++ -I/usr/local/include/svl vertex.hh vertex.cc`

Comment: I just tried with `-I` option and it is just the same

Answer (score 1):

Why are you compiling vertex.hh?  Why not just
    g++ vertex.cc

Secondly, can you show us the contents of your header file and source file.  Actually, the source file can probably be:

```
#include "vertex.hh"
int main() { return 0; }
```

and the header file:

```
#include "svl/SVL.h"
```

Secondly, when you say "#include " are you just including some of SVL internal headers?  That may not work.  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/doc/svl.html says "for basic use, the only header file needed is svl/SVL.h".

Comment: Hey, I added the header file and source file above through dropbox. And yeah, I am just including some internal headers like `vec3.h` and `vec2.h`.

Comment: I did the new `include` as you pointed out, `#include "svl/SVL.h",  and I have new sets of errors.

Comment: Right dropbox still shows you including internal header files.  _Don't do that._  Just insert the external header files like the documentation tells you to.  Dropbox doesn't show a #include of svl/SVL.h, so the obvious question is: is it above all the other includes?  (If not, I can imagine that causing difficulty.  Alternatively, the code may just not be C++11 clean.  Ask on the support mailing list (or whereever)?

Comment: yeah I did remove other includes and just included `svl/SVL.h`. The codes are outdated definitely but this is the one that i need to work with for now. So, i trying to find a way for it to work. there is sadly no support mailing list. I tried to contact the author but no reply.